# Can Facebook's Prophet be considered a “type” of AI? Like and CNN or RNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, machine-learning-model

I'm facing a problem to determine if the model [Prophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/) developed by Facebook team is some kind of Neural Network or similar.
Someone has an answer for it?

In [Github](https://github.com/facebook/prophet) repository has the following explanation: "Prophet is a procedure for forecasting time series data based on an additive model where non-linear trends are fit with yearly, weekly, and daily seasonality(...)".

But reading the [Prophet paper](https://peerj.com/preprints/3190.pdf), by Sean J. Taylor and Benjamin Letham. It really seems to be and Machine Learning algorithm.

Even the way that use it seems to be a Neural Network.

Any discussion or reference would be apreciate

Comment: Additive models are also ML algorithms. GAM are great to deal with wild non-linear patterns.

Comment: Thanks for your replying Peter! I had not sure about it.